# Is there a way to split a customer text attribute in Magento?

Tags: attributes, array, customer-attribute

I am trying to find a way to split a customer text attribute in order to display it on the frontend.

I have added a new text field to the customer address and would like to display this value on the frontend in View.phtml file. The problem is that the value is stored as a string depending on customer location for Euro we have €|c and for UK we have £|p stored in this field.

I need to some how split this value for display it in separate places.

I am using jQuery to validate a price form on the frontend. Customers from EU need to have the €|c value displayed and UK customer need to have the £|p displayed from the TextAttribute.

So I need to somehow get the customer attribute to show in the `product/view.phtml` file THEN split the array()

Here's my code:

```
    if (x<100) {
        //c OR p Value needs to go here
        validOptions.push( "<?php echo $address->getCurrency(); ?>"+x+"");
    } else {
        var y = x.toString();
        var z = y.split('');
        //£ OR € Value needs to go here
        validOptions.push("<?php echo $address->getCurrency(); ?>"+z[0]+"."+z[1]+""+z[2]+"");
    }
    x++;
```

Does anyone know how to do this please give me a heads up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following snippet to retrieve your attribute and split it on a **|**

```
$currency = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getData('your-custom-attributecode');
$currency_split = explode('|', $currency);
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, The code gives me the following result `Array1.00`

Comment: Try and echo `$currency_split[0]` or `$currency_split[1]` instead of `$currency_split`

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue? @user1704524

Comment: Yes, I had to tweak your suggestion slightly but it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, this works fine..

```
<?php $split = explode('|', $address->getCurrency());
  echo $split[0]; ?>"+z[0]+"."+z[1]+""+z[2]+"?>
```